# Check if master is up from slave server(replication) postgresql

Tags: postgresql, c#

I want to check whether my master server is up by querying from slave server ?
Is there any view or command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to write this as comment but I don't have enough reputation.
Did you tried, `pg_stat_wal_receiver`? It came with PostgreSQL-9.6.

```
dbs=# select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pid                   | 12345
status                | streaming
receive_start_lsn     | B0/F0000000
receive_start_tli     | 1
received_lsn          | CE/13C7B18
received_tli          | 1
last_msg_send_time    | 2018-09-26 16:15:25
last_msg_receipt_time | 2018-09-26 16:15:25
latest_end_lsn        | CE/13C7B18
latest_end_time       | 2018-09-26 16:15:25
slot_name             | 
conninfo              | connection info
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-WAL-RECEIVER-VIEW

Comment: Thank you.Its helpful :).I have stopped my master server and run this query in slave server,it returned 0 records.